# Windows batch: Iterate over mulitple files lines at the same time

Tags: file, cmd, batch-file

Is it possible to iterate over the lines of multiple files at the same time? I need to output a file by joining the lines in two different files (and add some extra words).

I know the CMD command:

```
FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
```

But that does not help if you need to iterate over two files at the same time.
More precisely, I need to the following:

```
While the first file is not ended
   line1 <- READ a line from the first file
   line2 <- READ a line from the second file
   WRITE on a third file line1 + line2
```

I'm looking for a way to accomplish what I'vve previously describing in a **dos batch** file. Thanks!

Comment: do you want to interleave the contents? You could use nested `for /f` to do that. Give us more detail so we could propose something.

Comment: @wmz: I've update my question. Please take a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know of 3 basic techniques, from which a large number of hybrids could be derived.

**Option 1** (this option is very similar to the wmz solution)

Read file 1 with a FOR /F and read file 2 with a second FOR /F with a SKIP option. File 2 must be read in a CALLed subroutine so that the loop can be broken without breaking the file 1 loop.

Limitations:

- Blank lines will cause lines to get out of synch. Blank lines are included in the skip count but are not read by FOR /F.
- Lines beginning with `;` will not be read because of the default EOL option. This can be solved by setting EOL to a new line character if necessary. See [HOW TO: FOR /F Disabling EOF or using a quote as delim](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=10729)
- Lines are limited to a maximum length of 8191 bytes.

This option is slow because of the CALL and because the 2nd file must be read once for each line.

*EDIT - code fixed to still output a line if 2nd file ends early*

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "file1=a.txt"
set "file2=b.txt"
set "out=out.txt"

set /a cnt=0
set "skip="

>"%out%" (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%file1%") do (
    set "found="
    call :readFile2
    if not defined found (echo %%A - )
  )
)
type "%out%"
exit /b

:readFile2
for /f "usebackq %skip% delims=" %%B in ("%file2%") do (
  set found=1
  echo %%A - %%B"
  goto :break
)
:break
set /a cnt+=1
set "skip=skip=%cnt%"
exit /b
```

**Option 2**

This option solves the blank line problem by using FINDSTR to prefix each line with the line number followed by a colon. FINDSTR is used to read only the nth line from file 2, so no need to break out of the 2nd loop.

Limitations:

- Leading colons will be stripped from the lines. This limitation can be eliminated with extra code, but it will make it more complicated and slower.
- Lines are limited to a maximum length of 8191 bytes.

This option is even slower than option 1

*EDIT - code fixed to still output a line if 2nd file ends early*

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "file1=a.txt"
set "file2=b.txt"
set "out=out.txt"

>"%file2%.tmp" findstr /n "^" "%file2%"
>"%out%" (
  for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "%file1%"') do (
    set "found="
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr "^%%A:" "%file2%.tmp"') do (
      set found=1
      echo %%B - %%b
    )
    if not defined found (echo %%B - )
  )
)
del "%file2%.tmp"
type "%out%"
```

**Option 3**

Use SET /P to read both files. FIND is used to get a count of the number of lines in file 1 because SET /P cannot tell the difference between a blank line and end of file.

This option eliminates a lot of limitations and complexity, but introduces its own limitations.

Limitations:

- Lines must use Windows style line terminators of `<CR><LF>`. Unix style `<LF>` will not work.
- lines are limited to 1021 bytes
- trailing control characters are stripped from each line.

This option is by far the fastest. It is preferred as long as the limitations are acceptable.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "file1=a.txt"
set "file2=b.txt"
set "out=out.txt"

for /f %%N in ('type "%file1%"^|find /c /v ""') do set "cnt=%%N"
>"%out%" 9<"%file1%" <"%file2%" (
  for /l %%N in (1 1 %cnt%) do (
    set "ln1="
    set "ln2="
    <&9 set /p "ln1="
    set /p "ln2="
    echo !ln1! - !ln2!
  )
)
type "%out%"
```

Comment: I like 3rd option - it's a clever way to do positioned read I have not thought of. Clear winner on efficiency/speed. Small note on first one though - it will stop echoing as soon as second file ends. If second file happens to be smaller than it will not output rest of fist file lines. That's why I finally used sets instead of directly echoing in inner loop `for` (which I also did in my fist version).

Comment: @wmz - Good point, and it applies to Option 2 as well. I've fixed both  options 1 and 2 to handle a file 2 with fewer lines.

Comment: Noob question: I'm trying the 3rd option and it's exactly what I came here looking for. But I don't want `out.txt`, just the `echo !ln1! - !ln2!`. I tried to `set "out=NUL"`, but that gives no output at all. I'm guessing it's integral to making this work? Or is it simply because the question asked for it, and can be done away with? If so please let me know. Otherwise I could just delete the file in the end.

Comment: @laggingreflex - Just remove entirely `>"%ou%"`, as well as the line that defines out and the line that TYPEs the out file.

Answer (score 2):

and now I have to deliver :-)

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /f "delims=" %%F in (outer.txt) do (
  set fline=%%F
  call :inner %%count%%
  call echo %%fline%%
  set /a count+=1  

)
goto :eof

:inner
if %1 neq 0 set skipline=skip=%1 
  for /f "%skipline% delims=" %%S  in (inner.txt) do (
    set fline=%%F%%S
    goto :eof
  )
```

Please note it may fail for some types of input, eg. when lines contain `&` or some other characters which are treated specially by the shell

Comment: Your FOR /F options are setting EOL to a quote character, and using TOKENS=* will strip leading spaces and tabs from each line. Better to use "DELIMS=". If worried about leading semicolon then need to set EOL to a new line character to effectively disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Appending file content:

```
echo FOO > foo.txt
echo BAR > bar.txt
type foo.txt > both.txt
echo "Both" >> both.txt
type bar.txt >> both.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this for 2 strings (might come in handy for someone else)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set string1=token1,token2,token3
set string2=2ndtoken1,2ndtoken2,2ndtoken3

for %%A in (%string1%) do (
    echo From String1: %%A

    set str2=
    for %%S in (!string2!) do (
        if not defined str2 (
            set str2=%%S

            echo !str2!%>tempfile.txt
            FOR %%? IN (tempfile.txt) DO ( SET /A strlength=%%~z? - 1 )

            REM echo StrLen=!strlength!
            echo From String2: !str2!

            call set string2=%%string2:~!strlength!%%
            REM echo String2: !string2!
        )
    )
)
```