# copy each line from 2 files to 1 file Windows batch

Tags: windows, for-loop, concatenation, batch-processing, findstr

I have to files and both have the same amount of lines, and I need to copy each line of both files to a new file, but concatenated. So line 1 of both files need to be copied to line 1 of the new file, and even with additional text in that line. This is part of a bigger Windows batch (cmd.exe).

input file "date.txt":

> 150102
>   150103
>   150104
>   150105

input file "ID":

> ID01
>   ID02
>   ID03
>   ID04

output file "Date_ID.txt" that I need:

> 150102 is the same as ID01
>   150103 is the same as ID02
>   150104 is the same as ID03
>   150105 is the same as ID04

Could anybody please help me with this? I tried things with /for and findstr but because it is looping I will get every combination of each date with each ID.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows batch: Iterate over mulitple files lines at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089002/windows-batch-iterate-over-mulitple-files-lines-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "file1=path_to\date.txt"
set "file2=path_to\id.txt"
set "out=path_to\output.txt"

for /f %%N in ('type "%file1%"^|find /c /v ""') do set "cnt=%%N"
 >"%out%" 9<"%file1%" <"%file2%" (
   for /l %%N in (1 1 %cnt%) do (
    set "ln1="
     set "ln2="
    <&9 set /p "ln1="
    set /p "ln2="
    echo !ln1! is the same as !ln2!
  )
)
type "%out%"
```

Comment: This is exactly doing what I asked for, brilliant! Thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure, I learned something as well. If it's working, please upvote/accept the answer.